# How to use api to get phabricator reviewer action

Tags: phabricator

I check `differential.query`, it can only return review status and reviewer phid. How can I get each reviewer action, such as reviewer A : Accept. review B: null(or need review/didn't review)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `differential.getcommitmessage` can return the result. The result is like

```
result
Review for branch f_20181012

Test Plan: Not Available

Reviewers: mike, bob

Reviewed By: mike

Differential Revision: http://phab.net/D17
```

Reviewed By is the reviewer who accept the revision.